# I have problem to use like and where clause together in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I want to select data from the SQL table and fetch data from the table with the use of LIKE and BETWEEN clause together and I have tried below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE  `date_time` LIKE BETWEEN '%2019-09-20%' AND '%2019-09-29%';
```

but it shows me the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN '%2019-09-20%' AND '%2019-09-29%' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat `date_time` as an actual date.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date_time`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-20', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-09-29', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

LIKE is only for comparing strings to a pattern that may contain wildcards; `Name LIKE 'Smith%'` -returns anything starting with Smith.

BETWEEN is for comparing numbers or dates to see if they fall into a range. Between includes the start and end values. `BETWEEN 1 and 5` returns any records that have 1,2,3,4 or 5

They cannot be used together, you use one or the other.

Dates are like decimal numbers; the time part of a date can mean the date falls outside of the range. Just like 5.5 is not "between 1 and 5", a date time of 2019-09-29 12:34 is not "between 2019-09-20 and 2019-09-29" - only midnight on the 29th will fall in the range. For this reason I tend to prefer using > and < with date ranges:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE
  `date_time` >= '2019-09-20' AND
  `date_time` < '2019-09-30'
```

This includes all records from the 20th to the 29th, no matter what time on the 29th. It's more clear and explicit than between. The other answer that has `BETWEEN ... 23:59:59` is also trying to capture everything less than the 30th but it's not such a wise habit to get into, because one day the time may have milliseconds etc

It's like saying `BETWEEN ... AND 9.9` because you're looking for values less than 10.. but the. One day revere is a value 9.99, and even if you used `BETWEEN ... AND 9.99` one day there will be 9.999 and so on. If you want "less than 10", use `< 10`

Try to only use BETWEEN for value ranges you know are discrete

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is useless here, you want the rows that date_time between 2019-09-20 and 2019-09-29, probably inclusive. so you can use below query, without LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2019-09-20' AND '2019-09-29 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subquery` to get your top matching date.

```
select * from `table_name` where `date_time` between 
    (select `date_time` from `table_name` where `date_time` like '%2019-09-20%' limit 1)  and   
    (select `date_time` from `table_name` where `date_time` like '%2019-09-29%' limit 1)
```